# Lost boot drive on raid 1 addition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, software-raid

I have 3 physical disk in my box, 1 ssd I was booting Ubuntu 16.04 from, then 2 4tb drives. I made a raid 1 array from the 2 4tb drives, but now cannot boot from SSD. What do I need or should I do? Did I mess up the `fstab` somehow?

Comment: A Linux live CD could be helpful to check on UUIDs vs FSTAB, Grub and Boot config files, and verify the Linux configuration side in general.  I suspect @appleoddity is putting you on the correct path the that issue is outside of your host OS and is due to a misconfiguration on the Hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If all you did was take a working system and add a RAID 1 volume from 2 4TB drives, then your BIOS is probably set to boot the RAID volume rather than the SSD drive. Go in to the BIOS and adjust the boot order so that the SSD is the first boot device.

If you changed modes of your existing SATA ports (from something like AHCI to RAID) so that in essence all drives are now connected to the "RAID" controller then the boot order might not be changed in the  BIOS. In this case, you may have to go into the RAID configuration utility (same place you created the RAID volume) and change the boot order there.